# Fastest way to Select Event that has no Joined Data

Tags: mysql, performance, exists

I have two tables:

```
Event
ID, StartTime

Video
ID, StartTime, Endtime
```

I need to find any event that has no video.

For this I have got the following query (well I have tried a fair few)

```
SELECT * FROM
(Select E.*,V.ID FROM Events E LEFT JOIN Video V On E.StartTime >= V.StartTime AND E.StartTime <= V.EndTime) A
HAVING V.ID IS NULL
```

This seems to produce the correct data, but it is too slow... (i have 100000 records in Events and 10000 records in Video). This takes approx 2 minutes to do. I have indexes on ALL the columns

Is there a quicker way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried removing the subquery?

```
SELECT E.*
FROM Events E 
LEFT JOIN Video V On E.StartTime >= V.StartTime AND E.StartTime <= V.EndTime
WHERE V.ID IS NULL
```

Or using `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT E.*
FROM Events E 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM Video V WHERE E.StartTime >= V.StartTime AND E.StartTime <= V.EndTime
)
```

Comment: I think the join in both suggestions will still be of the same order as the join in the original question, i.e. about a billion (10,000 x 100,000) virtual rows.

Comment: It won`t be in the second case as MySQL doesn't need to store anything from Video is a temporary table as those results are discarded. One of the main problems with the op's query is that he gathers all the possible combination in a temp table and THEN filters stuff out.

Comment: Thanks the `Not Exists` is slightly faster :)